# Recognising a string lowercase representation in python

Tags: python

I have a text file containing:

```
Madrid
Germany
Iceland
```

and a user is required to enter a country from the text file and the program will output the line where the country lies.

Lets say:

```
 enter country: Germany
```

output:
     2 #since germany is at line no.2

but I'm testing for cases where the user enters:

```
enter country: germany
```

where its lowercase at start. the program will still recognise it's lowercase representation and will still print the line Germany is at.

I'm looking for a method that recognises both lowercase and uppercase representation.

```
userinput = input("Enter country:").upper()
```

I've seen examples mentioning to convert the input to uppercase at start but the problem arises if my text file consists of letters with a mix of uppercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: `str.upper()` will  convert every letter to uppercase (not just the first letter). If you store all country names in your text file in full uppercase, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: or you can use userinput = input("Enter country:").title()

Comment: you can convert the text from file to uppercase too, in order to compare with the input text

Comment: for modern versions of Python, `str` has `casefold` that is a more aggressive version of `lower` (or `upper`) specifically for case-insensitive string matching. `if userinput.casefold() == line.casefold(): # hooray`. `str.casefold` is [new in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html?highlight=str%20casefold#builtin-functions-and-types)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
def fixcase(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return NotImplemented
    chars = list(string)
    chars[0] = chars[0].upper()
    for i in range(1, len(chars)):
        chars[i] = chars[i].lower()
    return str(chars)
```

will solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.fullmatch()` with `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
# Tested with 3.6.2
import re

search = input("Enter country: ")
file = open('countries.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()

for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
    if re.fullmatch(line, search, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(num)
```

This will only match the complete country name, and will ignore the case of the search term.

You could also use `re.match()` to check for a match starting at the beginning of the line, or `re.search()` to check for a match anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing string with unknown casing, but requiring only content of the string to be matched, You can use following code:

```
userinput = input("Enter country:")
with open(filename) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if userinput.lower() == line.strip().lower():
            do_something()
```

You can convert both string to lowercase and compare their content. Note `strip()` after getting line. If stored in file, line will contain newline character, so we need to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

We will convert the input to lowercase, strip new lines from the file and convert it lowercase, and compare the input with it.

Haven't used regular expression as you might not have knowledge of it

Have checked this it works:

```
inputx = input("Enter the country name: ")
inputx = inputx.lower()
file = open("tyt.txt","r")
data = file.read().splitlines()
lena = len(data)
for i in range(lena):
    reada = data[i]
    reada = reada.lower()
    if reada == inputx: 
        print("The line is: "+str(i+1))
```